# Is it possible to run WatchKit Extension from iPhone, not just simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit

My app currently displays user data (in this case it's the step count) which can not be simulated in the iOS simulator. I've always managed to get around this by testing the app on my iPhone. I'm nearing the end of development for my Apple Watch "Glance," yet I am unable to test if it accuratley gets the data from the phone and displays it. Yes, this is a BIG part of the app.

My question is, because my own iPhone (and not the simulator) has the data I need to access to test this Glance properley, is there a way to run the app through Xcode on my phone, while accessing the WatchKit simulator on my computer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'll update my answer if I can find a relevant dev forum thread (it's out there somewhere!), but there's currently no way to test using an IPhone and the Simulator in tandem.